# Getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException even though i've specified the correct jar with -cp

Tags: java, jar, classpath

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast

This bit is strange though, because i've added hazelcast-1.8.5.jar to the classpath when i'm running java:

```
java -cp hazelcast-1.8.5.jar -jar myapp.jar
```

So i cannot understand why i'm getting the ClassNotFoundException, when the hazelcast jar is well and truly present, and specified in the command line. Any ideas please?

By the way, hazelcast is pretty fricking sweet!

Comment: Hang on, is it something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910115/include-external-jar-when-running-java-jar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [-jar option docs](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html):
*When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.*

Comment: Ok, I see you figured it out yourself

Comment: Yes, i created a manifest file with the line "Class-Path: lib/hazelcast-1.8.5.jar" and compiled my jar with "jar cfm reconciler.jar reconciler.manifest reconciler/" then ran it with "java -jar myapp.jar". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set ClassPath in the JAR manifest.