# Execute jar file with multiple classpath libraries from command prompt

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath

I have a Maven project which generates a jar file and copies all dependencies to `target/lib` folder.  I want to execute this project on client's machine (windows).  So, I copied `myproject.jar` to `C:\xyz` folder and all dependencies to `C:\xyz\lib` folder.  How do I execute this project from client's command prompt?
I tried to use `java -cp lib\*.jar -jar myproject.jar` from `C:\xyz` folder but it throws following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lib\commons-codec-1/3/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar.  Program will exit.
```

I think if I specify all dependencies in classpath (like `java -cp lib\dep1.jar;dep2.jar`), it will get rid of the problem but I don't want to do this as I have 40 libraries already and it might grow in future releases.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let maven generate a batch file to start your application. This is the simplest way to this.

You can use the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/index.html) for such purposes.

Comment: When you use -jar, -cp is ignored. On the other hand, '-cp lib/*.jar' is the same as '-cp lib/dep1.jar;lib/dep2.jar...', I think from java1.5

Answer (score 81):

You cannot use both `-jar` and `-cp` on the command line - see [the java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#-jar) that says that if you use `-jar`:

> the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

You could do something like this:

`java -cp lib\*.jar;. myproject.MainClass`

Notice the `;.` in the `-cp` argument, to work around a Java command-line bug. Also, please note that this is the Windows version of the command. The path separator on Unix is `:`.

Comment: from what I read in the documentation, the * represents one or more jar files. So you need to say -cp lib\*; You should not use it in the normal sense (one or more characters)

Comment: Indeed, the *.jar didn't work for me (running on raspberry pi)

Comment: when tools that are supposed to make life easier for you actually cause more troubles...

Comment: I just want to add that this does not work currently PowerShell, but works find in CommandPrompt...

Comment: It's a real shame both `-cp` and `-jar` are not available together. I have a CLI program that requires the user to supply a JDBC library to use it properly, and packaging it as an executable JAR file presents a challenge, here.

Answer (score 68):

Using java 1.7, on UNIX -

```
java -cp myjar.jar:lib/*:. mypackage.MyClass
```

On Windows you need to use ';' instead of ':' -

```
java -cp myjar.jar;lib/*;. mypackage.MyClass
```

Comment: pfew, I've been looking for this for 30 minutes now, trying to run an application on raspberry pi. Turns out I just needed to replace the `;` separator with `:`. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. The windows version.

Answer (score 13):

Regardless of the OS the below command should work:

```
java -cp "MyJar.jar;lib/*" com.mainClass
```

Always use quotes and please take attention that **lib/*.jar** will not work.

Comment: Actually the command differs according to the OS, you should use semicolon in windows and colon in unix

Answer (score 3):

You can use maven-assembly-plugin, Here is the example from the official site: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>your main class</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

a possible solution could be

create a batch file

there do a loop on lib directory for all files inside it and set each file unside lib on classpath

then after that run the jar

source [for loop in batch file](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php) for info on loops

Answer (score 1):

There are several options.

The easiest is likely the [exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

You can also generate a jar containing all the dependencies using the [assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Lastly, you can generate a file with the classpath in it using the `dependency:classpath` goal.

Comment: Our client doesn't have maven installed on their machine.  Sorry, I should have mentioned this.

Comment: I can use assembly plugin but not exec plugin

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue but was able to package all dependencies into my jar file using the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-build-a-jar-file-that-contains-its-dependencies.html)

Answer (score -2):

This will not work `java -cp lib\*.jar -jar myproject.jar`. You have to put it jar by jar.

So in case of `commons-codec-1.3.jar`.

`java -cp lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar;lib/next_jar.jar` and so on.

The other solution might be putting all your jars to `ext` directory of your JRE. This is ok if you are using a standalone JRE. If you are using the same JRE for running more than one application I **do not** recommend doing it.

Comment: Wildcard classpaths are available in JDK 6+, the issue instead is that you can't specify both `-jar` and `-cp` at the same time. Putting your jars in your ext directory, IMO, is a pretty horrible idea.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah and this question is about executing a `jar` with its dependencies.

Comment: Yeah and you can do that with a wildcard classpath. Filling your ext directory affects *everything* you run, and is dangerous if you ever run *anything* else. It's a Maven project; use Maven.

Comment: @DaveNewton And how would you want to do it? Put the wildcard and then fully qualified name of the class which contains the `main` method? The whole idea of having an executable `jar` file is to avoid putting fully qualified name while executing and instead having it in the manifest file.

Comment: That, or by creating a jar with all dependencies, as I stated. And again, just throwing a single project's dependencies into a JRE shared across anything run with that JRE is nuts.

Comment: @DaveNewton Therefore my comment that if it is not a standalone JRE this is a bit cumbersome. I will rephrase it.

Comment: If by "cumbersome" you mean "will likely break everything else in the world", sure.