# JAR file behaving differently in a different place in file system

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have project called `test` in `Eclipse` which I want to export into Runnable `JAR` file. During the process of exporting the project, when I choose as a location of JAR file the subfolder of `test` folder in file system, such as `C:/.../test/App.jar`, it will work. However, when I want to put it for example on my desktop, it will run but in a very limited look (some GUI components missing) and it throws a lot of exceptions saying something like that:

```
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) xception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.WindowsGLDrawableFactory
       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
       at javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.getFactory(GLDrawableFactory.java}
```

What can be the problem? I assume it is not good that I have to specify my JAR file concretely into one folder in file system, it would become unuseful for any other potentional user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the jar needs other jars to execute. In this case you would have to set the classpath before you execute the jar

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt) might help you with your problem.