# How I run maven project in cmd line

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, cmd

I write maven project and I run it in Eclipse but I want to run maven project in using command line so I write

```
java -jar -Dapple.awt.UIElement="true" target/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -h
```

line in cmd but I have this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/c03mN.png.

How can I solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613857/noclassdeffounderror-while-executing-main-class-using-java-classpath-command/33616594#33616594

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 47):

You can run mavan spring-boot project using the following command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 42):

1. Move to your project root folder in command line - `cd ~/Project`.
2. `mvn compile`
3. `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.kub.App`

[Please check for more information here.](https://metamug.com/article/build-run-java-maven-project-command-line.html)

Answer (score 3):

Go to project :

1. open cmd
2. `cd c:/project`
3. `mvn clean install`
4. `java -jar -Dapple.awt.UIElement="true" target/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -h`

Add this in pom:

```
    <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.kub.App</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
     </plugins>
```

Comment: @question-maven-com I did your said but I have this error : could not find or load main class com.kub.App   but I run this project correctly in Eclipse but this project didn't work my cmd .How I solved it?

Comment: @question-maven-com my pom.xml as you say. It' correct. but I have still this error :( I import this maven project in my workspace in Eclipse  but this project is not seen  in my workspace directory  so I run this project download directory not  Eclipse workspace directory  so   Could this lead? I want to run this project in cmd but I did'nt

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are in the correct path for loading the .jar file?

maybe you need something like this?

```
java -jar -Dapple.awt.UIElement="true" USERS/eclipse-project/projectname/target/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -h
```

Comment: You might to extend your answer with more details. Otherwise, your answer might get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure that `JAVA_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` path are set in environment variables as follows:

   JAVA_HOME:  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181` (Path till JDK folder only not bin folder)
   MAVEN_HOME: `C:\Users\Amit Joshi\Downloads\apache-maven-3.6.0`
2. Add both paths in environment variable 'Path' as follows:
   `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`
   `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
3. Open your project using IDE (in my case I am using intelliJIDEA)
4. Click on Run button and copy the command executed in console window.
5. Open cmd and traverse to the root folder of your maven project.
6. Paste and execute the copied command and your project will run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have called the java command from an incorrect path ( i.e., Windows/system32 ) instead of your projects base directory .... cd to your projects base directory and try again .... That might solve your problem ....