# Can I get maven to run with this package structure and how should I change it?

Tags: java

I'm completely new to programming and I just built a Maven project with very poorly structured packages. Now, when I try to run my project from the terminal with the command `"mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=main.java.main.TakBoard"`, it won't run.
The error message is:

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'java-Dexec.mainClass=main.java.takgame.main.TakBoard' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0 among available goals exec, help, java -> [Help 1]
```

My github project link is [here](https://github.com/uradora/OT-Tak-Game/tree/master/TakGame), so you can see the structure.
Main class is in TakGame/src/java/main/takgame/main/TakBoard.java

I also tried to remove the last main class once and built the project again in NetBeans. Didn't work, so I added the main class again. How can I make this work without having the do the whole project all over again?

Comment: Structure should be `src/main/java` not src/java/main.

Comment: While links to external resources are fine to add context and clarity to your question, you need to include enough of your code **in the question itself** to make it answerable.  Links can break, and people may be blocked from accessing them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I run maven project in cmd line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977187/how-i-run-maven-project-in-cmd-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a java application, you need to provide the fully qualified name of the class that implements a main method. The fully qualified name consists of the package that the file exists in (which is the same as the diretory structure) and the class name.

With this

`... -Dexec.mainClass=main.java.main.TakBoard`

You're not using the package that you used for the class. I'm not really sure what you're using.

The package TakBoard is in is `takgame.main`. This means that the fully qualified name of the class is `takgame.main.TakBoard`. That's what you need to pass to the exec plugin's property.

`... -Dexec.mainClass=main.java.main.TakBoard`

As a side note - I'd suggest dropping maven. Instead, do all of the compiling and classpath management by hand on the command line (at least for a while). It's *way* more work. But you'll understand the classpath and package structures better for it.