# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I’m trying to run my program through the command line and i’m getting the above exception. I’ve compiled it through the cmd and it went fine. I am also running the program in Eclipse with no issues. Why do i get this exception from the command line?

Here is the full exception:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
… 7 more
```

Comment: classpath issue, check if you are providing those classes when launching the jar

Comment: I've already added the selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar as i so was recommended in another post but it didn't work as well.

Comment: they should be marked as runtime dependencies

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31523756/8918302). Hope this help.