# Eclipse projects stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: java, eclipse

I was just looking at my java project in eclipse, compiled it, and after closing program all projects in my solution show billions of errors.

Example:
`The import java.awt cannot be resolved`

When i try to compile it show error:
`A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again`.

Any clues how to fix it? I had many problems with java in the past and i couldn't fin any fixes, almost like it was designed to fail. This language vexes me, but sometimes you just have to use it.

Edit

I also get this error while attempting to open it in IntelliJ (just downloaded it):
`JDK jre.1.8.0_241 is missing`

Edit

Its just Java being Java (aka not working, as usual). You have to create new project and just copy everything to it, it will work.

Comment: Check your JDK configuration in Eclipse, which eclipse version you are using ?

Comment: 4.15.0. I will check it out but i doubt i find anything useful.

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381202/a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again-in-eclips

Comment: I have jre1.8.0_251 and Eclipse also uses it.

Comment: at the location check your jdk configured properly or not Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

Comment: Their solutions doesn't work. Creating new project and moving code works, but setting up resources again will be pure pain (last time adding 3 images took me like 2 hours, now it will be the same i guess).

Comment: @RakeshChouhan its set properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214602/discussion-between-rakesh-chouhan-and-gaijn).