# Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" within flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, javac

the problem with android licenses
and when i tried fixing it the problem was in java

when I typed  `flutter doctor`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.75.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

and when I typed
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`
this error appears
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
so can someone help:face_with_monocle:  note :the java and javac on my pc are the same version

Comment: You have not accepted the licenses , may be launch it once in Android Studio and accept the license ( this is what i do ) and it will be all good.

Answer (score 0):

run this command in the command prompt

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and type y and enter when you are asked.
and as you mentioned you are getting error here is the solution for your error that is given at another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31523756/14466860 check out this

Comment: i dont use java iam installing flutter

Comment: and the licenses doesn't work since this error of jdk

Comment: check out you have installed java or not ?

Comment: that is needed for android sdk

Comment: I get the exact same error with `flutter doctor --android-licenses`: => `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`. Also, with `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` =>`Matching Java Virtual Machines (2)`  `1.8.333.02 (x86_64)` and `1.8.0_111 (x86_64)` How do I fix it? Which do I remove & how

Comment: i installed java i have jre and jdk

Comment: the main problem that the flutter templates doesn't appears for me  ,so i think its related to the android licenses

Comment: run this command " java -version" in terminal and check what you are gettings

Comment: java -version
java version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: >javac -version
javac 19.0.2

Comment: this what appears

Comment: what is the main class of java as i don't use java or write code with it

Comment: uninstall the old version install new that might help you.

Comment: i reinstalled java

Comment: >java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.332-b09, mixed mode)

C:\Users\User>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: but javac isnt recognized

Comment: and  no java folder was made

Comment: watch i video and follow proper steps in installing i think you are making some mistakes in installation

Comment: i installed java with the same steps but the problem still there

Comment: @Pathros, have you found solution to your issue?

Comment: run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and check which Java versions installed, remove the old versions and try run the command again, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I started noticing these errors after upgrading to macOS 13. However I suspect they started after I upgraded to Android Studio Electric Eel (2022.1).

`flutter doctor` was reporting the following:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel flutter-3.2-candidate.5, 3.3.3-0.0.pre.2, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I symlinked the jbr director to jre according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75134478/700204). This resolved both complaints. No other action was required.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution working downloading latest version of java and update path to new jdk