# How to get my java program to launch from a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, launch

so I've just created a jar file for the first time. When I double click on it to run the program I get an error. "JNI error has occurred please check your installation". My program is terminal based. How do I get my program to open the terminal when launched. Thanks!

Comment: This link should also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381202/error-a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again-in

Comment: This did not help