# Using jar file in another project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have one jar file, named `pwd.jar` and I want to use that in another project named `sample`.

How can I do that? What are all the steps I should perform?

Note: I am using Eclipse IDE

Comment: you can set the classpath properly. Use an IDE like Eclipse for doing this with some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-jar-from-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Since 2002 there has been a tool called maven that provides a systematic way to handle dependencies between projects; later, another tool called ivy was introduced that focuses purely on dependency management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your project-> properties->Java Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add External jar, and browse your jar

Cheers