# ClassNotFound when running main() through reflection but works fine with java -jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file which I runs fine with `java -jar my-jar-file.jar`.

But now I have to load the main class from another java program using reflection and when I do that I get a `ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException`.

The code I'm using to do that:

```
URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{new File("my-jar-file.jar").toURI().toURL()});
Class<?> serverClass = loader.loadClass("com.foo.bar.application.MyMain");

Method main = serverClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
String[] params = new String[]{"-flag", "value"};
main.invoke(null, (Object) params);
```

The stacktrace is like this (removed details):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
```

I also tried adding entries from `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` to the array of `URL`s I pass to class loader, but no luck as well.

This error seems reasonable to me as the jar file does not contain `javax.mail.MessagingException` (does not contain `javax.mail` package actually) but how does it work when I just do `java -jar my-jar-file.jar`?

How can I fix this issue? Thanks

edit:

Added MANIFEST.MF contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.foo.bar.application.MyMain
Implementation-Version: 1.5.4
```

edit 2:

One more thing worth to mention is that the jar file contains a `javamail.providers` file in `META-INF` directory. Suppose this somehow makes that jar to work, but how can I do the same programmatically?

`javamail.providers` contents:

```
# AWS Mail Provider
protocol=aws; type=transport; class=com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport; vendor=Amazon Web Services LLC;
```

Comment: If you open the jar file, and open the manifest inside, it will have a `Class-Path` entry.  That's how it will find the class when you run it from the command line.  When done programmatically from a classloder, I don't think it uses that manifest though.

Comment: @sstan Nope, the `MANIFEST.MF` file does not contain such entry. I updated the question with its contents.

Comment: Looks like the javax mailing jar is not in your class path. How exactly are you running the program that is not working (e.g. from cmd line with  java -cp some.jar com.mypackage.MyClass). More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-jar-from-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Comment: @serejja: I'm, with you. No idea how you're getting `java -jar my-jar-file.jar` to work in the first place.

Comment: @John I run it with `java -cp my-another-jar.jar com.foo.bar.AnotherMain`. That AnotherMain contains code that I described above. I understand that it seems I have javax mailing missing from classpath, but the thing that really bothers me is why does it work when I just `java -jar` the jar file I'm trying to invoke from my code?

Comment: Try: java -cp "my-another-jar.jar;lib/*;javax.mail.jar" com.foo.bar.AnotherMain. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath (an have the javax.mail.jar in the directory you are running from).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this solved by adding `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);`:

```
URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{new File("my-jar-file.jar").toURI().toURL()});
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
Class<?> serverClass = loader.loadClass("com.foo.bar.application.MyMain");

Method main = serverClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
String[] params = new String[]{"-flag", "value"};
main.invoke(null, (Object) params);
```

Now everything works as expected and I don't get `ClassNotFoundException` anymore, but I still don't quite understand why this works. It seems to me that it was trying to load additional classes/resources with a different `ClassLoader` and thus was failing to do that, and by calling `setContextClassLoader` I'm explicitly saying to use the provided `ClassLoader`.