# Reference jars outside of a jar

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

I am working on a java application that depends on several jars such as args4j, groovy, jasperreports, etc.

I would like to package just **my code** into a run-able jar while still referencing these external jars, perhaps by piping them into the one with my code somehow. Is there a way that I can do this?

I am fairly new to java, so simpler answers are probably better. Also, I plan to run this application from Windows command-line.

**edit:** Just to farther clarify, I have some compile-time dependencies and some run-time dependencies. I want the run-time dependencies to not be packaged into my jar so that the jar size is not so big.

**edit 2:** This is not a duplicate. Firstly, I am not using eclipse. Secondly, I am not trying to package external jars within the jar I am creating.  Instead, I would like to keep them outside of the jar I am making and somehow specify to use these external jars when I go to run my jar.

Comment: You say "*to package just my code*" and then "*by piping them into the one **with** my code*".  Seems like a self-contradiction.  The way I understood  your needs - you need to look into using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) or [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html).

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstanding me. I would like the classes that I wrote to be placed in a jar that does not include the jars they depend on. At run-time, I would like to specify these dependency jars in the command line, perhaps piping them in somehow. Sorry if  this is seems like a stupid question, I am new to Java.

Comment: In such case my advice to look at Maven and/or Gradle stands.

Comment: I already have. Again, I am a java beginner. Most of the documentation for Maven and Gradle seems to be aimed for experienced java programmers and is difficult to understand. I am looking for a simple answer.

Comment: How do you expect those "*external*" JARs to appear on customer's system?

Comment: That is not an issue, but the reason for wanting this separation is simply a company preference. For the purpose of organizing our in-house binaries and such.

Comment: Are you asking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar) question?

Comment: No, if I understand correctly what he is asking. I am not trying to reference jars contained in another jar. I am trying to separate the dependent jars from a jar that contains just my code, and be able to specify when I run my jar that it uses dependent jars located at "c:\...\somedirectory" when I go to run mine.

Comment: Then just add this *somedirectory* to your [`CLASSPATH`](http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html).

Comment: So for example _java -jar myjar.jar -cp c:\...\somedirectory_  ?

Comment: Then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18413058/2055998