# Maven not building sqljdbc intelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, sqljdbc

I am trying to build my maven project in IntelliJ.
I added the dependency in the `pom` file as shown.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc4-2.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I also have the `sqljdbc4-2.0.jar` in the `/lib` folder.
I am able to successfully clean the project and package it. However, when i run the jar on my linux machine it gives me following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Please help. Struggling with this for quite some time. Thanks.

Comment: Do you specify the classpath when you run the jar? Maven will not package your dependencies in your jar file. There are however a number of maven plugins that will let you do so.

Comment: I am on my linux machine and i run: `java -jar file.jar`.  Can you help me in how do i specify the classpath ? I am kind of new to java. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks. Might work. Do i need to have the `sqljdbc4-2.0.jar` file on my machine directory where i am running my project's jar ?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you very much. I got it working.