# How do I add Derby Client to a Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am building an app in Java, using Eclipse and Derby as DataBase. 
I have aready added Derby Client to my project and everything goes perfect.

My problem is that when I run my app from the CMD or comand line; I get the error message: Not suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/...

How can this be solved?

Thanks before hand!

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, just to make sure you already have Derby jdbc driver in your classpath. You can check for its versions and download [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath)
2. Secondly, when you run your app from CMD, make sure you specify the classpath which should include your Derby jdbc driver. You can follow the [guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath) which mentioned:

> You have two options:
>
> 1.include all jar files from the lib directory into the manifest (you
>   can use relative paths there)
>
> 2.Specify everything (including your jar)
>   on the commandline using -cp:  java -cp MyJar.jar:lib/*
>   com.somepackage.subpackage.Main