# Java ClassPath with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I'm working on a java project and trying to run a jar file. I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Most of the other threads I've read, said that it was because I needed to use the `-classpath` option. However, I've tried implementing this a couple of ways and I'm getting the same error, still.

The last way that I tried to implement the `-classpath` option and execute the jar file is shown below.

```
java -classpath "/full/file/path/file.jar" -jar file.jar
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

`-jar` is for self-contained jars.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413058/20394 explains that `-classpath` is ignored when `-jar` is specified.  Just do `-jar /full/file/path/file.jar` if it is a self-contained jar.  If it's not, you will need to use `-classpath` and make sure all its runtime dependencies are available via that classpath.

If you haven't already, it might be worth learning to use a build system like `mvn` or `bazel` to manage the class path for you, or to try running your class through an IDE like Eclipse.