# Using external third-party properties file with Spring Boot Fat Jar

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, atlassian-crowd

I have a Spring Boot app that will be deployed as a fat jar. It integrates with Atlassian's Crowd for authentication. This requires a `crowd.properties` file to be available on the classpath. I would prefer to not bundle the properties file (which includes a password) with the jar.

**Is there a way to tell Spring Boot to include another file or directory for where to search for property files?**

When doing this with a standalone/external Tomcat in the past, I would use the `shared.loader` property in `catalina.properties` to specify a directory where additional property files would be available.

I've tried including the file in the root location of the jar, as well as a `/config` location, but to no avail. Atlassian also has a page that indicates using a `-Dcrowd.properties=...` command line parameter to set this, but also to no avail.

Note: This is *not* referencing `application.properties` in external locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to figure this out with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44679126/2601060), specifically the section under "Original answer".

It turns out that a two part solution was required.

1. The spring-boot-maven-plugin needed to have some configuration set. By setting the `layout` to `ZIP`, it will use the `PropertiesLauncher` rather than the `JarLauncher`, which (I believe) allows you to use the loader properties.

`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <layout>ZIP</layout>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2. Using the `-Dloader.path=/folder/with/property/file/` command line parameter to provide the location of the properties file. Note: this must come *after* the `-jar` parameter.

For more information on the **why**, read on.

Based on the Spring documentation for "[Launching Executable Jars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-launching)", there are three launchers to load the files for an application. By default the `JarLauncher` is used, which limits the locations you can retrieve resources. The `PropertiesLauncher` on the other hand will look in `BOOT-INF/lib/` but also in `loader.path`, which you can provide additional folders.