# Unable to access directory classes after setting classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I'm having a hard time setting the classpath for a directory to a package of classes. I'm trying to run a jar file that takes a directory as a command line argument. The program uses the directory to access class files in a folder and uses reflection to explore the class fields and methods.

```
final File folder = new File(args[0]);
classList = dirParse.listFilesForFolder(folder);
```

I then go through the classList, get the name of each class, and use the `Class.forName()` method to access the classes.

```
Class c = Class.forName(className);
```

For the line above to work, I have to set the classpath to the address of the directory containing the classes.

I can get the program to run just fine when I'm using a directory of classes that do not belong to a package like below:

```
java -cp "Explorer.jar:/Users/john/Desktop/TestClass/" explorer.ExplorerDemo /Users/john/Desktop/TestClass/
```

However, for the following line, monopoly is a package and the program throws a `ClassNotFoundException` after calling `Class.forName(className)`

```
java -cp "Explorer.jar:/Users/john/Desktop/Programming\ Project/Monopoly/build/classes/monopoly/"  explorer.ExplorerDemo /Users/john/Desktop/Programming\ Project/Monopoly/build/classes/monopoly/
```

For testing purposes, I tried adjusting `Class.forName() call to include the package name like below:

```
Class c = Class.forName("monopoly."+className);
```

However, this also throws `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName` is a shortcut to obtaining class information within the context of ClassLoader of the current class. Javadoc states that this is equivalent to

> Class.forName("Foo", true, this.getClass().getClassLoader())

Provided that you class directory is supplied as runtime parameter and is not part of the original classpath, I would suggest you instantiating custom `URLClassLoader` instance that will be pointing to your directory.

Sample code:

```
public class ReflectionClassAnalysis {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        // URLClassLoader supports both directories and jar files
        Path directory = Paths.get("/some/directory/");
        Path jar = Paths.get("/some/binary.jar");

        // You may be interested in providing parent ClassLoader for your new instance
        // You can either use current class ClassLoader like
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = ReflectionClassAnalysis.class.getClassLoader();
        // or current thread ClassLoader
        // ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        URLClassLoader myClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[]{
                    directory.toUri().toURL(),
                    jar.toUri().toURL()
                },
                contextClassLoader
        );

        // You may use ClassLoader directly to load class meta
        Class<?> externalClass = myClassLoader.loadClass("your.class.name");
        // or supply ClassLoader to forName method
        // Class.forName("your.class.name", true, myClassLoader);

        // Do your class analysis here
    }

}
```

For JAR with classpath instructions please refer to: [Run a JAR file from the command line and specify classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath)

Comment: So in your approach, you wouldn't even need to set the classpath?

Comment: No. You will set it programmatically for new ClassLoader.

Comment: I'm sure your approach works, but I'd like to figure out how to do this using the classpath.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Comment: What do you mean by "directory is a package"?

Comment: if the classes in the directory I want to access have some package declaration at the top such as `package monopoly;` I get the `ClassNotFoundException`. If the class files have no package declaration the program works fine.

Comment: Seems I get it. When you specify the classpath Java creates a URLClassLoader for you (very close to my example). The URLClassLoader expects the provided directory to be a root of your class folder structure. I don't believe you can have it different. The code internally does loading by substituting `.` with `/` in class name and looking for a `.class` file at this relative path on disk.

Comment: so if my 'monopoly' folder contains my classes and all the classes have  `package monopoly;`, then `Class c = Class.forName("monopoly/"+className);` should work if my classpath is `/Users/john/Desktop/Programming\ Project/Monopoly/build/classes/monopoly/`, right?

Comment: If I got it right the classpath should be just `/Users/john/Desktop/Programming\ Project/Monopoly/build/classes/`

Comment: I tried that. Got this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: monopoly/GameController`