# Run my own program packaged in Spring boot jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

I have a util class which has a main method.  After packaged by Boot Maven plugin, it ends up in BOOT-INF/classes. It does need some other libraries packaged under BOOT-INF/lib.  Is there a quick way using the cmdline to run that program, without unzip the jar?  Thanks!

Comment: Is that main class the spring boot's main class? Or other?

Comment: If is an executable jar and the dependencies are specified in the manifest or inside the jar just use, java -jar myjar.jar. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Comment: No, it's my own class, and is not specified in the manifest.

Comment: You can use command like `java -cp myjar.jar MyMainClass`.