# ClassNotFoundException:org.postgresql.Driver on running project as jar file

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc

My project is a maven project and i use JDBC - postgres driver to run a few queries in the java program. I used maven-jar-plugin to get an executable jar on maven build. When i run jar as java -jar xyz.jar, I get

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.postgresql.Driver"

I checked manifest.mf file and I could see postgres in classpath as below:

> Class-Path: postgresql-42.1.4.jar

Please favour on resolution. This same code runs well as Java application. It only creates problem when it is a jar file.

Maven-jar-plugin in pom.xml is as below:

```
 <dependencies>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.4</version>
    </dependency> 

  </dependencies>
    <build>
          <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.app.App
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
             </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
```

Comment: Are you running this as a JAR with dependencies packaged into the JAR?  If not, where does the Postgres JAR reside?  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Comment: it is inside maven dependency..tha's it. i have added pom.

Comment: Is the postgresql-42.1.4.jar in the same folder as your own jar when you try to execute it? If not: that is your problem.

Comment: is there a way to get all maven dependencies into this same jar ? like..packaging dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that the postgresql artifact is not packaged into the xyz.jar.
in your case, the postgresql jar have to be in the same level as the xyz.jar
- xyz.jar
- postgresql-42.1.4.jar

and that will works.

In case of the java application, the needed jar's are installed in a lib folder and the application resolved the dependencies from the folder.

Comment: is there a way to package postgres into jar , instead of keeping jar explicitly?

Comment: You can do this using the maven-assembly plugin with the "jar-with-dependencies" descriptor [link] (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)