# Class-Path ignored when running jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

My MANIFEST.MF in my application jar contains the following line:

```
Class-Path: other.jar
```

My directoy contains the followign files at the same level:

```
- myApp.jar
- other.jar
```

I run my application using

```
java -jar myApp.jar
```

and get a NoClassDefFoundError for a class which is in other.jar

What am i missing please?

Comment: did you try this post --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Comment: I am not specifying jar and cp as cmd line arguments. If anything i am using the answer in that post. my jar which is declard in my manifest.mf is ignored.

Comment: can you try to give absolute path of jar in manifest.mf?

Comment: still get the same error with an absolute path (and can't use absolute path either way as a final solution as this needs to work on several environments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was outside of the manifest file. I had an autogenerated index.list file next to it which blocks classpath from being read.

Comment: Index.list should only be an issue if it was *inside* myApp.jar and *wrong*.

Comment: it is autogenerated using maven assembly plugin so it is always there and won't fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Class-Path the last line in the Manifest file?Then it should have an extra line at the end. It may not read the class-path if there is no carriage return in the end.

Comment: there is a new line at the end