# Kotlin javax.script support example

Tags: java, kotlin, jsr223

I tried to compile the [javax.script example from the Kotlin web site](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support).

```kotlin
import javax.script.*

fun main () {
  val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!
  engine.eval("val x = 3")
  println (engine.eval("x + 2"))  // Prints out 5
}
```

But it throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
$ kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
$ java -jar hello.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt:4)
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt)
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here? Do I need some additional compile options?

I am using:

```
kotlinc-jvm 1.4.10 (JRE 11.0.9+11-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
```

#### Update: some more tests

```
$ kotlinc-jvm hello.kt 
$ kotlin HelloKt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/ScriptEngineManager
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt:4)
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.AbstractRunner.run(runners.kt:64)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.run(Main.kt:149)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.main(Main.kt:159)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 9 more
$ kotlin -cp .:kotlin-stdlib.jar:kotlin-main-kts.jar:kotlin-compiler.jar:livetribe-jsr223.jar HelloKt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt:4)
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.AbstractRunner.run(runners.kt:64)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.run(Main.kt:149)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.main(Main.kt:159)
$ java -cp .:kotlin-stdlib.jar:kotlin-main-kts.jar:kotlin-compiler.jar:livetribe-jsr223.jar HelloKt
ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory not found
ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider org.jetbrains.kotlin.mainKts.jsr223.KotlinJsr223MainKtsScriptEngineFactory could not be instantiated
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt:4)
        at HelloKt.main(hello.kt)
```

`NullPointerException`s everywhere, although ["Kotlin's type system is aimed to eliminate NullPointerException's from our code"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Funny. Somehow.

#### Update: Java example

I want to port the following Java/Groovy example to Kotlin/Kotlin.

Source

```java
import groovy.util.Eval;

public class MetaEval
{
  public static void main (String... args)
  {
    System.out.println (Eval.me ("2+3"));
  }
}
```

Compile

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac -cp .:/usr/share/java/groovy-all.jar MetaEval.java
```

Run

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp .:/usr/share/java/groovy-all.jar MetaEval 
5
```

Comment: Engine for `kts` extension is not a part of JVM (and not a part of kotlin runtime). I believe you are missing some dependencies in classpath when running jar. Maybe [this one](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/008da87160c3704846dab2b18c0c9055dbab95cc/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/build.gradle.kts#L19)?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь How to specify this in the command line?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing, **javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory** file in you project. If you look at at [full example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example) in the release notes document you linked, you will see the project has `javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory` file under `META-INF/services/` directory.

You need similar setup in your project and content of the file will be:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory
```

this should get you going.

Comment: I would like to compile it without Gradle as in the Java example.