# Java classpath issue '.' vs. './*'

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to compile and run from the command line a simple java hello world program.

It compiles and runs successfully when I do:

```
> javac HelloWorld.java
> java HelloWorld
```

However, when I place a jar-dependency in this hello world program and the corresponding jar in the same directory, I run into a classpath issue.

I can compile with:

```
> javac -cp ./* HelloWorld.java
```

But I when I attempt to run while specifying the classpath to the jar, my HelloWorld class is not found.

```
> java -cp ./* HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

When classpath is `./*`, the jar is found but not the class, and when classpath is `.`, the class is found but not the jar.

I also tried specifying both, but the main class is not found whenever I use a `:` in the classpath.

```
> java -cp "./*:." HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

How can I specify classpath for java to find both the jar and my class?

Comment: Does `HelloWorld.java` specify a package?

Answer (score 1):

In powershell, one solution is to use `;` instead of `:`.

I.e. this works in powershell:

```
> java -cp "./*;." HelloWorld
hello, world
```

The idea to try that came from an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath) question:

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but PowerShell is incidental to it, given that both `"./*;."` and `"./*:."` are passed _verbatim_ through to `javac` as  `./*;.` and `./*:.`, respectively. The problem sounds like it's related to _platform_ differences: On Unix-like platforms, search paths containing a list of directories, such as contained in the `PATH` environment variable, use `:` as the entry separator, whereas on Windows it is `;`