# Trying to run Java JAR file (JavaFX) but getting "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"

Tags: java, javafx, jar, intellij-2020

[screenshot of trying to run the JAR file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmWzo.png)

In IntelliJ, everything is running fine, but when I try to run exported JAR file, this error appear, why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Kenji,  I think you need to add a classpath, that includes the JavaFX runtime jar, when you run your jar.  Maybe this other question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath