# Access Class at runtime with reflections from JAR file

Tags: java, linux, reflection, jar

I'm working on a correcting system for assignments for students. Let me try to break my problem down into a simple example.

The projects I want to check look like this:

- project-name

  - src

    - Task1

      - Solution1.java
      - Solution2.java

Now I want to check if the project has a correct implementation, but I can not assure, that Solution1.java exists, so I'm using reflection to access the classes.

I'm copying a package into the src folder, so the new project looks like this.

- project-name

  - src

    - Task1

      - Solution1.java
      - Solution2.java
      - Correction

        - Correction.java

I don't know, if the Solution.java actually exists, so I'm using reflections.

```
Class.forName("Task1.Solution1");
```

Now I'm compiling everything inside the project and run the Correction.java - file in Linux.

This works fine so far.

In order to speed up the process, I tried to create a Solution.jar file, so I don't have to compile the file for every project. When I run the jar-file I'm getting a ClassNotFound exception, when I try to access Solution1.
The jar file lies within the Correction-package.

I'm starting inside the src folder, and I run:

```
java -jar ./Correction/Correction.jar
```

Does anyone know, why this might be happening?

Comment: How are you running your JAR file?

Comment: Starting inside the src folder I run:

`java -jar ./Correction/Correction.jar`

Comment: Well, that is your problem. When using `-jar`, the class path is entire defined by the JAR, so it doesn't see the custom classes that aren't part of the jar (and what is defined in the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest). You will need to use `java -cp .:./Correction/Correction.jar name.of.your.MainClass` (if you're on Windows, separate classpath entries with `;` instead of `:`).

Comment: See also: [Run a JAR file from the command line and specify classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath)

Comment: I'm not sure, if understood correctty. But my Main-Class is inside the jar file. I want to access the other files via reflections from within the .jar file.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to access classes **outside** your JAR using reflection.

Comment: Alright. I tried `java -cp ./Task1/*:./Correction/Correction.jar Path.To.MainClass.Inside.JAR`. 
But I'm still not able to acces the class Solution1.

Comment: Did you actually compile `Solution1`? Does `Solution1.java` have a package statement, if so, what is its value? Is there a `Solution1.class` in the `src/Task1` directory?

Comment: `Solution1` is compiled and the `.class`-File lies within the `Task1`-Folder. The package declaration is also `Task1`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `-cp ./Task1/*:./Correction/Correction.jar`, but `-cp .:./Correction/Correction.jar`

Comment: Oh, well. That's working, nice. Thank you.