# passing properties file to a jar in Dockerfile

Tags: java, dockerfile

I have jar for my java app, which needs a properties file to be provided from outside to make it run. I want to create a docker image for it.

Is this the correct approach for image creation:

```
FROM openjdk:8

COPY somepath/myapp.jar myapp.jar
COPY custom.properties .
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/myapp.jar"]
CMD ["-cp", "/custom.properties"]
```

Comment: What issues are you experiencing with that approach? Currently, your questions asking for "the correct" approach seems to be opinion-based. Do you have specific requirements?

Comment: are you working with someone else? if yes, agree on the method and stick with it.

Comment: I think your CMD syntax is inappropriate, look at that answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath

Answer (score 1):

this looks like a opinion based question, your approach is correct and works fine if that's what you want as an answer.
just a small tweak in your ENTRYPOINT

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "/myapp.jar:/custom.properties", "your.main.ClassName"]
```

if you want to ask something else specific, kindly edit your question.