# Trying to run a POI-dependent class on Command Prompt

Tags: java, apache-poi, command-prompt

As the title says, I'm trying to run a class in Command Prompt which uses the Apache POI library but when I run this command:

```
java -cp C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\libs; HyperlinkWriter
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

the libs folder contains the entire POI folder that's zipped up when downloaded so I'm not sure why it's throwing this error. I also tested this with IntelliJ and it ran fine. I know that the way Command Prompt and IntelliJ handles libraries is different but I'm not sure why this is happening.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Is the library containing the POI jars unzipped?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if the jars are unzipped?

Comment: yes, is the folder you downloaded containing the POI library unzipped?

Comment: The jars are still zipped but `poi-bin-3.12-20150511.zip` is unzipped

Comment: Are all the .jar files from your download in that directory, e.g. "poi-3.12-20150511.jar", etc.?

Comment: I'd check for extra POI jars.  I just had a similar issue using a maven build and there were conflicting versions declared.  If you have more than one jar containing the class org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper I would expect a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: @rgettman all the .jar files from the download are in the directory

Comment: @BoatCode i checked for extra POI jars but I didn't find any extra jars containing the class

Comment: Jars in a directory isn't normally enough. What happens if you explicitly list them on the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from a previous [answer of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018244/2038087). I had to add a '*' to the end, and a '.' after the semicolon. So with my example, in terms of compiling, I had to do:

```
javac -cp C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\libs\*;. C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\src\HyperlinkWriter.java
```

and then to run it (Credit to @andrewdleach), I just did:

```
java HyperlinkWriter
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually compile the jar with the original .java files and the specified POI jars.

```
javac -cp \path_to_jars \path_to_java_files
```

and then

```
java MyProject
```

Comment: I tried `javac -cp C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\libs C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\src\HyperlinkWriter.java` but it gave a bunch of errors leading from the fact that the compiler complained that the POI packages didn't exist

Comment: Have you removed any extra .class files?

Comment: I removed all of the ones generated by IntelliJ but I'm still getting the errors

Comment: Not only compile, but run too! You need those jars listed on the classpath for the `java` runtime command too!

Comment: @Gagravarr I know that but I can't run it unless I can compile it