# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running my java program

Tags: java

i'm new with java.
when i come to run my java app i'm getting this error below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException
```

the issue it is ALSO happens when i'm adding the classpath to my command:

```
java -jar myApp.jar -classpath .\lib
```

BUT,
when i'm copy myApp.jar to the lib direcotry and running form there it's working fine.

thanks for the help guys.

Comment: What build tool are you using ? you need to make sure that org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException is in the runtime class path. If you are using maven the delete your old manifest and do a mvn clean install on your project to regenerate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: i used maven. but where is the mainfest file? i don't find it.

Comment: Should be in your target folder ... Just try mvn clean install it should regenerate it.

Comment: already did it but it did not help

Comment: does you pom pull in the right jar ? and the import statement pulls in the right class ?

Comment: sorry, didn't understand your question: does you pom pull in the right jar

Comment: pom.xml has the correct jar in its dependencies ?

Comment: yes it has. i double checked that. that's why when i put my app in the lib directory (where maven download the jars to) it working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use both -jar and -classpath at the same time. If you use -jar, it will ignore your -classpath and use settings from the manifest in the jar. Try all in the classpath:

```
java -cp myApp.jar:lib/*:. mypackage.MyClass
```

On Windows you need to use ';' instead of ':'

```
java -cp myApp.jar;lib/*;. mypackage.MyClass
```

See similar question here: [Execute jar file with multiple classpath libraries from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt)

Comment: {java -cp cloneXl-0.0.1.jar:lib/*:. com.xxx.myJavaTraining.CloneXL
Error: Could not find or load main class com.xxx.myJavaTraining.CloneXL}

Comment: That's weird... try:   java -cp cloneXl-0.0.1.jar:lib:. com.xxx.myJavaTraining.CloneXL

Comment: Is this being run from the same directory that the jar lives in? Since it's being specified by -cp, it won't warn you if the path doesn't point to anything. Also, double-check the jar - if you open it, does it contain the class you are intending to use? Other than that, I'm out of ideas.