# How to run a Jar-file with external libraries?

Tags: java, jar, libraries

When I run the Jar-file inside netbeans it works.
But after I clean and build it, it won't run.
It gives me an error, that the Mainclass couldn't be found.

I tried already something like:

```
java -cp C:\javaProjectsTests\J.jar;C:\javaProjectsTests\lib\*;. j.J

java -Djava.library.path=C:\javaProjectsTests\lib\* -jar C:\javaProjectsTests\J.jar
```

Maybe someone could help?

Answer (score 3):

Please refer below link
[Execute jar file with multiple classpath libraries from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt)

Lod your jars to classpath and execute your class (with main method)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

It was a syntaxerror in the path-string.

It works now, but only if the lib-folder(other jar-files) is in the same directory as the executing jar-file. Should not a problem for comandline programs, as it's possible to use a batch-file to execute from somewhere else.

However I asked me if it's possible to merge archives, as I could read on a website [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)  ?