# Package mysql-connector jar along with my project

Tags: executable-jar, mysql-connector

I have a simple JDBC project that fetches data from a database. I have used `mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar` for jdbc connection.

Now I want to create an executable jar of my project from command line (not from eclipse).

I tried using :

```
jar cfe myJar.jar com/demo/MySqlJDBC com/demo/MySqlJDBC.class
```

The jar was created, but it doesn't contain `mysql-connector jar` and so when I run the jar as:

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

I get error like:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

So, my question is how can I pack the `mysql-cnnector-jar` while creating jar of my project without using maven and eclipse (just from command line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute jar file with multiple classpath libraries from command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt) and most importantly all answers are 5 years old and suggest to use maven. I am trying to use command line only.