# Getting error "Error: Could not find or load main class" when there are multiple jar files in java -cp command

Tags: java

I have 3 jar files A.jar, B.jar, C.jar.  C.jar contains a class com.rb.test.PResolver.java having main method.  C.jar has dependency on A.jar and B.jar.  When I try to run PResolver class using following command, the main method gets invoked, but it fails, since the dependent jar files are not in classpath:

```
java -cp C.jar com.rb.test.PResolver
```

When I try to add the dependent jar filed in -CP option, then the class is not found:

```
java -cp A.jar:B.jar:C.jar com.rb.test.PResolver
```

Above command gives following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.rb.test.PResolver
```

So the moment I put the dependent jars in the -cp option of java command, the class is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all your jar files in a folder lib and then try:

- for unix: `java -cp  C.jar:lib/*:. com.rb.test.PResolver`
- for Windows: `java -cp  C.jar;lib\*;. com.rb.test.PResolver`

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt) for details to see how you can execute jar with multiple classpath libraries from command line