# Add external properties to classpath for maven dependence

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift

I have an spring-boot application deployed on Openshift.
This application is dependent on a plain old java application, which has been added as maven dependence.
The maven dependence requires a `foo.properties` file on the classpath, it loads the `foo.properties` file using:

```
inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/foo.properties");
```

The `foo.properties` file will contain different values depending on the environment it's deployed to.
I have tried to externalise the properties by adding a configmap to openshift, and mounting it at: `/deployments/config`

I have added spring properties to the openshift environment variables:

```
spring.config.name foo
spring.config.location /deployments/config/
```

However the maven dependence is unable to pick up the `foo.properties`, returning null.

Is what I'm attempting achievable, or are there alternative solutions to this problem?

Comment: have you tried smth. like: `java -cp "directory where foo.properties is located" -jar myapplication.jar` ?

Comment: It's not possible to use -cp and -jar together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by configuring OCP4 Environment Variables: `JAVA_MAIN_CLASS`, `JAVA_CLASSPATH`

```
JAVA_MAIN_CLASS=-Dloader.main=your.spring.application.class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

JAVA_CLASSPATH=/deployments/your.spring.application.jar:/deployments/data/:.
```

It's not possible to use both `-jar` and `-cp` on the command line: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#-jar

Answer (score 1):

**spring.config.location** has nothing to do with java native **getResourceAsStream** method, therefore it doesn't help

For JVM to interpret **/deployments/config/** as part of your classpath, you have to include this folder to the classpath in java command.

You probably have a Dockerfile with this line

```
java -jar service.jar
```

Modify it to

```
java -cp service.jar:/deployments/config mypackage.MyApplication
```

Comment: It's not possible to use -cp and -jar together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt

Comment: You're indeed right, modified the answer, you would need to put jar to "cp" argument and manually specify main class.