# Include multiple external jar files in classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I have a MyProgram.jar for which I need some exernal jar-files. It is not possible to move these files, so I need to reference them. I tried:

`java -cp C:\Test\MyProgram.jar;C:\OtherLocation\other.jar test.myprogram.UI`

(and I need some more jars)

However, when I try this, I get the exception:
Could not find or load main class Files

The program starts if I leave out the OtherLocation, like this:
`java -cp C:\Test\MyProgram.jar test.myprogram.UI`
but then I'm missing libraries.

It looks like the question below, but apparently this does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

[include external jar when running java -jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910115/include-external-jar-when-running-java-jar)

Comment: Do you have empty spaces in the _OtherLocation_ path ?

Comment: Yes, that is not allowed? Can I somehow escape it?

Comment: Look at the duplicate topic, it has many solutions for this.

Comment: try java -cp "C:\Test\MyProgram.jar;C:\OtherLocation\other.jar" test.myprogram.UI   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: Ugh, I'm sorry, I have tried so many things today regarding the classpath that I totally overlooked this. Thank you for helping me :)