# Running a jar - JSONObject throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I have built a program in java, and running it in **IntelliJ** is fine, but when I build the artifact (jar) and run it in the command prompt on my computer, it throws the `IllegalArgumentException`.

I am using `java-json.jar` as my library to make a string (that is in JSON form) into a JSON object so that I can iterate through it and display the information as needed.

Here are the results of running the program in CMD:

```
    C:\Users\DeskTop\IdeaProjects\OperationGamerProfile\out\artifacts\OperationGamerProfile_jar>java -jar OperationGamerProfile.jar
Thank you for choosing Operation Gamer Profile!
Please read the manual that was provided with this tool so that you know how to use it...
Lets get started...

The client ID is: (My client ID)
The client Secret is: (My client secret)
Please enter your authorization token(This is CASE SENSITIVE): (my token)
Result from blizzard: {"characters":[{"name":"Netherfry","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":5,"race":8,"gender":0,"level":5,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/27/163571995-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherwarz","realm":"Darkspear","battlegroup":"Cyclone","class":9,"race":5,"gender":0,"level":5,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"darkspear/130/86434434-avatar.jpg","guild":"GeekyGaming","guildRealm":"Darkspear","lastModified":0},{"name":"Hailnether","realm":"Akama","battlegroup":"Reckoning","class":1,"race":2,"gender":0,"level":2,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"akama/235/95051243-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Hailnether","realm":"Khaz Modan","battlegroup":"Cyclone","class":2,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"khaz-modan/53/101812021-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Hailne6EA459","realm":"Greymane","battlegroup":"Shadowburn","class":5,"race":11,"gender":0,"level":0,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"greymane/89/91137113-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherdrew","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":11,"race":8,"gender":0,"level":91,"achievementPoints":1470,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/134/156092806-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Guardian","role":"TANK","backgroundImage":"bg-druid-bear","icon":"ability_racial_bearform","description":"Takes on the form of a mighty bear to absorb damage and protect allies.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Staff, Polearm","order":2},"guild":"EndlessVoid","guildRealm":"Bleeding Hollow","lastModified":1429907056000},{"name":"Hailnether","realm":"Wyrmrest Accord","battlegroup":"Cyclone","class":3,"race":4,"gender":0,"level":3,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"wyrmrest-accord/146/109003154-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherwraith","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":9,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":16,"achievementPoints":1305,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/72/157163336-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Affliction","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-warlock-affliction","icon":"spell_shadow_deathcoil","description":"A master of shadow magic who specializes in drains and damage-over-time spells.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Staff, Wand, Dagger, Sword","order":0},"lastModified":1411674035000},{"name":"Nethermonk","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":10,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/13/157523981-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherhunt","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":3,"race":2,"gender":0,"level":11,"achievementPoints":1380,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/245/163559157-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Marksmanship","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-hunter-marksman","icon":"ability_hunter_focusedaim","description":"A master sharpshooter who excels in bringing down enemies from afar.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Bow, Crossbow, Gun","order":1},"guild":"EndlessVoid","guildRealm":"Bleeding Hollow","lastModified":1425762452000},{"name":"Netherlock","realm":"Cho'gall","battlegroup":"Vindication","class":9,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":16,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"chogall/88/110060376-avatar.jpg","guild":"Mindless","guildRealm":"Cho'gall","lastModified":0},{"name":"Bi?¬zzard","realm":"Bloodhoof","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":1,"race":2,"gender":0,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bloodhoof/42/108061994-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherman","realm":"Cho'gall","battlegroup":"Vindication","class":3,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":20,"achievementPoints":1370,"thumbnail":"chogall/223/109983711-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Marksmanship","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-hunter-marksman","icon":"ability_hunter_focusedaim","description":"A master sharpshooter who excels in bringing down enemies from afar.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Bow, Crossbow, Gun","order":1},"guild":"IliilBARCODEliilI","guildRealm":"Cho'gall","lastModified":1425698021000},{"name":"Yoursbaby","realm":"Moon Guard","battlegroup":"Reckoning","class":5,"race":1,"gender":1,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"moon-guard/213/116473301-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Hailne652387","realm":"Bladefist","battlegroup":"Vengeance","class":5,"race":11,"gender":0,"level":2,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bladefist/135/107291527-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Aazzdf","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":1,"race":2,"gender":1,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/145/164662417-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Nethersquad","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":10,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":0,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/36/157524004-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Darknether","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":6,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":62,"achievementPoints":1380,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/118/156625270-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Unholy","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-deathknight-unholy","icon":"spell_deathknight_unholypresence","description":"A master of death and decay, spreading infection and controlling undead minions to do his bidding.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Two-Handed Axe, Mace, Sword","order":2},"lastModified":1425841594000},{"name":"Lpeodke","realm":"Hellscream","battlegroup":"Rampage","class":5,"race":1,"gender":1,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"hellscream/115/106721395-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0}]}

Starting JSONObjects
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.OperationGamerProfile.Main.main(Main.java:52)

C:\Users\DeskTop\IdeaProjects\OperationGamerProfile\out\artifacts\OperationGamerProfile_jar>
```

Here is the `htmlGetRequest` method:

```
private static String htmlGetRequest(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Here is the code with the JSON:

```
try {
        //getting data
        String result = htmlGetRequest(url);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Starting JSONObjects");

        ***//ERROR STARTS HERE***
        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);

        System.out.println("Built object");

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("characters");

        System.out.println("Built Array");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String gender;
            if (explrObject.get("gender").toString().equals("0")) {
                gender = "Male";
            } else {
                gender = "Female";
            }

            String charClass = "";
            switch(explrObject.get("class").toString()) {
                case "1": charClass =  "Warrior"; break;
                case "2": charClass =  "Paladin"; break;
                case "3": charClass =  "Hunter"; break;
                case "4": charClass =  "Rogue"; break;
                case "5": charClass =  "Priest"; break;
                case "6": charClass =  "Death Knight"; break;
                case "7": charClass =  "Shaman"; break;
                case "9": charClass =  "Mage"; break;
                case "8": charClass =  "Warlock"; break;
                case "10": charClass =  "Monk"; break;
                case "11": charClass =  "Druid"; break;
                case "12": charClass =  "Demon Hunter"; break;
            }
            System.out.printf("Information of character %d:\n" +
                            "\t Name: %s\n" +
                            "\t Level: %s\n" +
                            "\t Gender: %s\n" +
                            "\t Class: %s\n"
                    , i+1, explrObject.get("name"), explrObject.get("level"), gender, charClass);
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Done displaying JSON Data...\nExiting program...");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At first I was getting `NoClassDefFoundError`, and ended up finding the **classpath** in **IntelliJ** and pasted this into it: `"set classpath=%classpath%;.;"`, that seemed to fix the problem of the class not being found, but led to the error of `IllegalArgumentException`.

If anyone is able to help here, I would greatly appreciate it, if you need anymore details of the program, I am happy to provide them.

`result` contains: Result from blizzard:

```
{"characters":[{"name":"Netherfry","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":5,"race":8,"gender":0,"level":5,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/27/163571995-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherwarz","realm":"Darkspear","battlegroup":"Cyclone","class":9,"race":5,"gender":0,"level":5,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"darkspear/130/86434434-avatar.jpg","guild":"GeekyGaming","guildRealm":"Darkspear","lastModified":0},{"name":"Hailnether","realm":"Akama","battlegroup":"Reckoning","class":1,"race":2,"gender":0,"level":2,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"akama/235/95051243-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Hailnether","realm":"Khaz Modan","battlegroup":"Cyclone","class":2,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"khaz-modan/53/101812021-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Hailne6EA459","realm":"Greymane","battlegroup":"Shadowburn","class":5,"race":11,"gender":0,"level":0,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"greymane/89/91137113-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherdrew","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":11,"race":8,"gender":0,"level":91,"achievementPoints":1470,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/134/156092806-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Guardian","role":"TANK","backgroundImage":"bg-druid-bear","icon":"ability_racial_bearform","description":"Takes on the form of a mighty bear to absorb damage and protect allies.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Staff, Polearm","order":2},"guild":"EndlessVoid","guildRealm":"Bleeding Hollow","lastModified":1429907056000},{"name":"Hailnether","realm":"Wyrmrest Accord","battlegroup":"Cyclone","class":3,"race":4,"gender":0,"level":3,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"wyrmrest-accord/146/109003154-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Nethermonk","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":10,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/13/157523981-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherwraith","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":9,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":16,"achievementPoints":1305,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/72/157163336-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Affliction","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-warlock-affliction","icon":"spell_shadow_deathcoil","description":"A master of shadow magic who specializes in drains and damage-over-time spells.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Staff, Wand, Dagger, Sword","order":0},"lastModified":1411674035000},{"name":"Netherhunt","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":3,"race":2,"gender":0,"level":11,"achievementPoints":1380,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/245/163559157-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Marksmanship","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-hunter-marksman","icon":"ability_hunter_focusedaim","description":"A master sharpshooter who excels in bringing down enemies from afar.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Bow, Crossbow, Gun","order":1},"guild":"EndlessVoid","guildRealm":"Bleeding Hollow","lastModified":1425762452000},{"name":"Netherlock","realm":"Cho'gall","battlegroup":"Vindication","class":9,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":16,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"chogall/88/110060376-avatar.jpg","guild":"Mindless","guildRealm":"Cho'gall","lastModified":0},{"name":"Biìzzard","realm":"Bloodhoof","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":1,"race":2,"gender":0,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bloodhoof/42/108061994-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Netherman","realm":"Cho'gall","battlegroup":"Vindication","class":3,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":20,"achievementPoints":1370,"thumbnail":"chogall/223/109983711-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Marksmanship","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-hunter-marksman","icon":"ability_hunter_focusedaim","description":"A master sharpshooter who excels in bringing down enemies from afar.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Bow, Crossbow, Gun","order":1},"guild":"IliilBARCODEliilI","guildRealm":"Cho'gall","lastModified":1425698021000},{"name":"Yoursbaby","realm":"Moon Guard","battlegroup":"Reckoning","class":5,"race":1,"gender":1,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"moon-guard/213/116473301-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Hailne652387","realm":"Bladefist","battlegroup":"Vengeance","class":5,"race":11,"gender":0,"level":2,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bladefist/135/107291527-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Aazzdf","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":1,"race":2,"gender":1,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/145/164662417-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Nethersquad","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":10,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":0,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/36/157524004-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0},{"name":"Darknether","realm":"Bleeding Hollow","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":6,"race":10,"gender":0,"level":62,"achievementPoints":1380,"thumbnail":"bleeding-hollow/118/156625270-avatar.jpg","spec":{"name":"Unholy","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-deathknight-unholy","icon":"spell_deathknight_unholypresence","description":"A master of death and decay, spreading infection and controlling undead minions to do her bidding.\r\n\r\nPreferred Weapon: Two-Handed Axe, Mace, Sword","order":2},"lastModified":1425841594000},{"name":"Lpeodke","realm":"Hellscream","battlegroup":"Rampage","class":5,"race":1,"gender":1,"level":1,"achievementPoints":0,"thumbnail":"hellscream/115/106721395-avatar.jpg","lastModified":0}]}`
```

Sorry for the spaghetti code...

Comment: Please copy the stacktrace from cmd to your post and remove the attached picture.

Comment: @samabcde Done :)

Comment: Is `result` really a parseable `json` `string`? If so, you should probably change the name of the `getHTML` method.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Oh, I see how that could be a confusing name. `getHTML` is going to blizzard and requesting my character list from them. I'll edit the post and give you the contents of `result` at the bottom of it.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I'm going to change getHTML to htmlGetRequest, because it is a get request, thanks for the input on that. :)

Comment: For future, there is no `System.out.println("Result: " + result);` in you console before error. it means that the source of the error are lines before : `htmlGetRequest(url);`.

Comment: @uli It was there, I took it out so that the code screen wasn't so large, but now I see how it is needed. At the bottom of the post the string is posted. I'll update the post to reflect the actual cmd screen fully, sorry...

Comment: I have added the full console result, as well as the `htmlGetRequest` method, and the `result` string.

Comment: Are you using `org.json.simple.JSONObject ` ? What version of it are you using? From [github](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONObject.java) it has no arguments constructor or `public JSONObject(Map map)`. There is no version with string.

Comment: In my imports I am using `import org.json.JSONArray;`
`import org.json.JSONObject;`
But what confuses me is that it works when I run the program in IntelliJ, just not in the command prompt.
Could it be something with the project structure itself? Or how the jar is processed?

Comment: This is strange JSONObject can throw only JSONException and not a IlegalArgumentException. Are you using maven? Have you build jar with dependency? Try to add to your pom [plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: I don't know what maven is, so I don't think I am using it. Could it be that the library file with the jar isn't being found by the command prompt?

Comment: Then you are missing dependencies. Just `java -jar OperationGamerProfile.jar` is not enough. Look into [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910115/include-external-jar-when-running-java-jar)

Comment: I'll take a look, Thanks!