# Include a runtime JAR when running a fat JAR

Tags: java, jar, classpath, fatjar, wiremock-standalone

Pretty sure this is a duplicate question, but couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

I'm trying to run WireMock standalone with WebHook extensions. Both come packaged as JAR files. First one, `wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.28.1.jar` is a runnable fat jar and it works like a charm when I type:

```
java -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.28.1.jar
```

*WebHook extensions* (`wiremock-webhooks-extension-1.0.0.jar`) is a normal JAR that contains a class `org.wiremock.webhooks.Webhooks`. I'm trying to run WireMock this way:

```
java -cp wiremock-webhooks-extension-1.0.0.jar                 \
     -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.28.1.jar --extensions org.wiremock.webhooks.Webhooks
```

And I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wiremock.webhooks.Webhooks
```

What I get from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910115/include-external-jar-when-running-java-jar) is that if `-jar` is specified on the command line, `-cp` is ignored and `MANIFEST` is used instead. So I've tried

```
java -cp wiremock-webhooks-extension-1.0.0.jar:wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.28.1.jar  \
    com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner                 \
    --extensions org.wiremock.webhooks.Webhooks
```

but got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
```

Of course, HttpClient is part of WireMock dependencies.
WireMock standalone JAR manifest is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerR
 unner
```

I want to run the fat JAR, adding an external JAR to the classpath, but with no original dependencies ignored. How can I achieve this?

Comment: i have the same problem did you find some solution?